# Find creation date of Google App Engine project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

So I created a project on Google App Engine roughly 2 years ago, but I don't know the exact date anymore. I would like to find that date now, but I'm having no luck with that, I cannot seem to find that information in the new Cloud Platform overview at https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?project=PROJECTNAME - I am pretty sure it was available in the old app engine overviews somewhere?

Anyhow, my [two](https://google.com) best [friends](https://stackoverflow.com/) in such cases could not help me, unfortunately, unless I missed something in which case I am terribly sorry.

So the question remains, how do I find the date of creation of that project? 
Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the Cloud SDK to do this :)

```
gcloud projects describe <YOUR PROJECT ID>
```

This includes a bunch of data, including the date.  Hope this helps!

Comment: This failed big time for me. It spent a whole minute slowly going back in time one month at a time, then after 2 years it just gave up. This project is probably more than 10 year old.

Answer (score 7):

Go to the Manage resources page in the GCP Console. Select the project, then on ACTIVITY tab shows all the project activity including created date.

https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to get the project's create timestamp via the following 2 links:

1. [get_proejct](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudresourcemanager/latest/google.cloud.resourcemanager_v3.services.projects.ProjectsAsyncClient?authuser=0#google_cloud_resourcemanager_v3_services_projects_ProjectsAsyncClient_get_project) in ResourceManager V3
2. create_time attribute in [class project 1.9.0](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/cloudresourcemanager/latest/google.cloud.resourcemanager_v3.types.Project?authuser=0)

You'd need to write Python 3 code to call the Resource manager client library. The 1st link has the Python sample code where you'd put name_value to be `projects/415104041262`